# List Notebook Sections with OneNote API on SharePoint Online

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

When I try to list the sections of a notebook on SharePoint Online using the `OneNote API (GET https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myorganization/siteCollections/{site-collection-id}/sites/{site-id}/notes/notebooks/{notebook-id}/sections)`,

I get the following error message:

```
{
    "error":{
    "code":"10001","message":"An unexpected server error has occurred. Please try again later.","@api.url":"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=400804"
    }
}
```

I can add a new section to the notebook using the `OneNote API (POST)`, though.

With the `OneNote API on OneDrive` for Business (Office 365) this works perfectly.

Comment: Hi Adrian, can you provide us the X-CorrelationId header of the HTTP response you get from that request so we can diagnose this?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax below should work and I have tested it:
https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myorganization/siteCollections/{site-collection-id}/sites/{site-id}/notes/sections